# how do i install java packages?

Tags: java, maven, installation, netbeans, package

this is probably a realy stupid question. I want to use a set of packages to build a simulation model. i downloaded the packages but i realy cant figure out how to install them. there is a realy short installation guide but it does not say much more than how to decompress the contents [http://webhotel4.ruc.dk/~keld/research/JAVASIMULATION/](http://webhotel4.ruc.dk/%7Ekeld/research/JAVASIMULATION/) i dont know where to put the folders after i extracted them.

btw i am using netbeans. i learned how to code in java but i never learned to install packages

Comment: That package is 17 years old... I think you need to do it fully manual... Maybe you can find more up-to-date packages which are available via Central repository?

Comment: @khmarbaise That software is 21 years old. The website is 17 years old. And it's some version of the programming language Simula. There is a more [recent](https://portablesimula.github.io/github.io/) effort.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Then I would ask why are those artifacts not available via Central repository... apart from that: The site says: `Version 1.1 (March 2004)` ... which is linked on the site...

Comment: @khmarbaise Because no one added it to maven. Also, *javaSimulation has been described in the report K. Helsgaun, "Discrete Event Simulation in Java",
DATALOGISKE SKRIFTER (Writings on Computer Science), 2000, Roskilde University.*  Here is [Professor Keld](http://webhotel4.ruc.dk/~keld/)'s current site.

Comment: [1] Questions of the form _"Please help me understand {something}"_ are usually off topic on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to ask about a _specific problem_ you are facing, rather than just seeking general help and advice. [2] With regard to using downloaded code in a Maven project, a search on SO using "[maven] dependency" may be helpful. [3] There is also the Maven documentation [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), although that may be a bit overwhelming as a starting point.